# I am a new linux user . i use ubuntu 20.04 . after installing it i was going to enable fingerprint

Tags: login, thinkpad

i was going to enable fingerprint login . after enabling it , i select right index finger but it shows " Fingerprint Device Storage Is Full " . so I cant add any fingerprint . so how do i delete fingerprint data ? need solution .

Comment: Please edit to add more information about your hardware, and also, how you enabled fingerprint login.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that there is a setup option to reset fingerprint data before you boot the operating system.